# Currying and Brackets in function calls

Tags: haskell

I have a hard time to understand Currying in Haskell. I was not able to understand the already existing answers to this topic. I want to understand what the difference is between:

```
(Int -> Int) -> Int
```

and

```
Int -> (Int - > Int)
```

I think the answer has something to do with currying. I have already consulted some resources about the topic and I have got an idea.

Functions that have several parameters can be described as an array of elementary operations with one input and one output.

According to the online tutorial learnyouahaskell:

"Doing max 4 5 first creates a function that takes a parameter and returns either 4 or that parameter, depending on which is bigger. Then, 5 is applied to that function and that function produces our desired result."

So in this case the elementary basic operations are just comparing two values. And the first operation is

if "lowest value possible" `> 4` then "lowest value possible" otherwise 4

The second operation is

if 4 > 5 then 4 otherwise 5

This would represent `Int -> (Int -> Int)` but what would `(Int -> Int) -> Int` be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

is the same type as

```
Int -> Int -> Int
```

and is the type of a curried two-arguments function, both being integers. That is it is a function which takes an integer argument and returns a function, whose argument is another integer, and which finally returns an integer.

Possible calls are `f 3 2` and `f (7+4) (5*8)`.

Possible definitions are `f a b = a+b` and `f a b = a*a+42*b`.

Instead,

```
(Int -> Int) - > Int
```

is not a binary function, curried or not. It is a function with a single argument, and this argument is a *function* `Int -> Int`. The final result is an integer.

Possible calls are `f (\x -> x+1)`, `f id`, and `f g where g n = n*4+5`.

Possible definitions are `f h = h 45` and `f h = h (h 6) + h 7 + 9`.

Comment: What would be the first and second function, for the function with the definition f a b = a + b?

Comment: @RM777 In such case, `f 3 = \b -> 3+b`, i.e. `f 3` is the function which adds 3. Essentially, `f` takes `3 :: Int` and returns the function `\b -> 3+b :: Int -> Int`

Comment: So with the same logic: max 4 = \b -> compare 4 b?

Comment: @RM777 No, `max 4 = \b -> max 4 b = \b -> if b>4 then b else 4`. The function `compare` only returns one of `LT,EQ,GT` stating if the first argument is less than/equal to/greater than the second. It does not return a number.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of partial function application is a hallmark of Haskell.
Exploiting partial application is natural. It is much how we think.
I fill my glass half with tea. Then I fill it completely with lemonaid.

`m2 = max 4` --partial application (Int -> Int)

`m2 5`       -- full application (Int -> Int) -> Int

All functions in Haskell are curried. It is sometimes necessary to disable it with `uncurry`

`m3 = uncurry max`

`m4 = m3 4` -- does not become (Int -> Int)

`m4 3`  -- is not (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int

Does not work and the error has to do with partial application (Int -> Int) because the function now requires two parameters.